# Internet Explorer 6 - DIV problems

Tags: internet-explorer-6, html

I have a website setup with DIV managed layout. The problem is that under IE 6 this layout breaks.
[image]

[image]

This is the CSS:

```
#bg{
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0; 

        /* Preserve aspect ratio */
        min-width:100%;
        min-height:100%;
}
#basic {
    width: 902px; height:  auto; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; position:  relative; padding-bottom: 50px;
}
#logo{
    width: 902px; height: 400px; position: absolute; top: 17px;
}
#navbar{
    width: 902px; height: 23px; top: 280px; position:absolute; 
}

#content{
    width: 802px; height: auto; top: 325px; position: absolute; background-color: white; padding-top: 50px;padding-left: 50px; padding-right: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px
}
#csob{
    width: 100px; height:100px; bottom:0px; right: 0px; position: absolute;
}
#titulni_strana {width:902; height:auto; top:325px; position:absolute}
```

PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://protechp.cz/zimnihrycsob/images/favicon.ico">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
<link href="default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<title>Zimni Hry CSOB</title>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="unitpngfix.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<img src="images/background-gradient-ok.jpg" id="bg" alt="pozadi">
<div id="basic">

<div id="logo">
<center><img src="images/logo3.png" alt="logo"></center>
</div>

<?php include ("./menu.php") ?>

<div id="titulni_strana">
<img src="images/titulni_strana.jpg" alt="titulni strana">
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please post the code for the section that is breaking

Comment: I advise validating your html source in http://validator.w3.org/  many times invalid html are excused by other browsers

Comment: I read an article the other day about HTML. It basically frowned upon web developers that said they weren't going to support IE6 on their website... well, I won't frown upon you :)

Comment: @Dalton Conley who said here that he is not going to support IE6? Whom you won't frown upon? Or you just wanted to mention that you read an article about HTML the other day?

Comment: I'm simply planting the idea of not supporting IE6, that is all.

Comment: Sadly the client, a bank, has IE6 on 2/3 of their computers.

Comment: validator.w3.org is giving me 8 problems, but they are all related to missing alt attributes on images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It look as if there are issues here beyond just simple CSS.

First, ensure your HTML is valid. It looks as if the browser in the first image is being more lenient than IE6 since the image is broken in one but not the other.

Also, IE6 does not support the min-* properties. You need to use height and width instead, either in an IE6-only stylesheet or with the star hack to target IE6 only.

Edit: Also, IE6 does not support fixed positioning.  You'll need to use absolute positioning for it instead.

Comment: The first image is any browser outside of IE6. Firefox 2,3 support this website, chrome does, safari does.
The min properties are there for the gradient background, it is the only way I've found to do the gradient background.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is with the image not loading and not the css.

Try removing the style sheet, all css, and the ie6 png fix javascript just to confirm your image is making it to the page as it doesnt look like a css problem to me. A live example would be nice.

Comment: I've actually found that it was the Fixed attribute in CSS. Sadly now the automatically resizing background no longer works.